# Resharper. How to add custom command (template)?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, templates, resharper

I use Visual Studio 2010 and ReSharper 6.1. I often need to create some variables/constants in upper case. So, how can I make custom command in ReSharper to apply variable/const name in Upper Case?
For example I typed the next code:

```
private const string myStoredProcedure1 = "something";
```

and I need convert it to

```
private const string MYSTOREDPROCEDURE1 = "something";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go into Code Style settings for C#, you can specify the ways you want variables names, including ALL UPPERCASE, which is probably what you want. After you apply this, R# will complain about all variables that aren't in the correct case and will offer you the option to automatically change them.

Comment: Right. One way to streamline the process is to choose "Find similar issues" in the pop-up menu invoked with Alt+Enter as soon as you stumble upon one of those rename suggestions. This would give you the entire scope of required changes.